# Example code and documentation on using Firmata communication in native Java

Tags: serial, library, communication, firmata

I have been trying for some time to get documentation on using Java and a Firmata client library for the communication between a PC and an Arduino. Please note I want to use Java only, i.e., not Processing.

Up to now I used the excellent Haskell library [hArduino](https://hackage.Haskell.org/package/hArduino) for Firmata communication with Arduino boards.

Now I am teaching a Java course at the university as a PhD student. Therefore I need to use Java. However, compared to Haskell there are no centralized libraries, packages, documentation as with Haskell.

So I used Google to find more information on using Firmata client libraries for Java. Unfortunately, the search results are polluted with irrelevant results about Processing and Javascript. Therefore I ask here.

According to the Firmata [client library page](https://github.com/Firmata/Arduino), there are two Java client libraries. However, only [4ntoine](https://github.com/4ntoine/Firmata) seems to be up to date, while the [Javarduino](https://github.com/shigeodayo/Javarduino) project seems abandoned.

So I guess the standard way is to use the ["4ntoine"](https://github.com/4ntoine/Firmata) Java client library. Or are there other options?

(I am not interested in Processing or Javascript.)

*Question: Where do I find up-to-date documentation and example code on using Firmata client libraries for Java?*

Comment: Can someone create the firmata and java tags?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can work for you.
Some months ago i used RXTXcomm library [1] to send Arduino data to a Program i made in java and store in in a file, it works fine with some issues:

- I made the Java programm in linux but just works in java 6, so in the windows pc of the client i installed that version, i don't know if works with java7 or java8 in windows.
- Java programm reads data from Arduino sketch with Serial.print() function, Arduino continously is using this function, i lose some data, so i had to put a short delay to java programm get all data send by Arduino.

[1] http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [JArduino](https://github.com/SINTEF-9012/JArduino) can give you some useful information.
Check the native code in jardunio.core.

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon because they don't add much value. Please expand your answer with information on why it is useful or make a comment instead.